# How can UIScrollView automatically wrap the content?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I'm desperatly trying to find any solution for my `UIScrollView` issue, I know there were a lot of discussions in this forum but I couldn't find any suitable solution.

My issue is that I only have labels and images, which are loaded from a database, in my `scrollview`. So I don't know how long the labels are. My `scrollview` has i.e. a height of 615 (in interface builder), if I initialize this `scrollview` with this height, it won't scroll.

So my question is how do I know what my height is, after I have loaded the text from my database? I also have a navigation bar and a tab bar in this `ViewController` if that does matter for the height?

The structure of my viewcontroller looks like this:
 - NavigationController
    - ViewController
     - View
      - ScrollView
       - Label1
       - Label2
       - Label...

Comment: set contentSize and FramSize of ScrolllView programmetically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take following small steps:

- Set your scrollview size not more then size of screen (i.e (320, 480) till iPhone 4 and (320, 568) for iPhone5) like:

  ```
  CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
  UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)];
  ```
- now set content size of your `scrollView`

  ```
  [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, heightOfAllSubViews + heightOfVerticalSpaces)];
  ```

  here `heightOfAllSubViews` is cumulative  height of all the labels and imageView, and `heightOfVerticalSpaces` is cumulative height of all vertical spaces between subviews. That's it in my knowledge you'll be good to go after doing this.

Comment: thank you for your answer but how is it possible to calculate the height of all white spaces?

Comment: Amm when I say white spaces i actually mean the vertical space between labels and imageViews. I have updated my answer for same. :)

Comment: OK, now I'm gettin the correct height but I have now an other issue -.-

When i'm scrolling down and then clicking on an other tab item in my tab bar and then going back to this UIScrollView i can't scroll up anymore. I have to click again on an other tab bar item and go back again to the UIScrollView, then it is correctly shown again. This is pretty uncomfortable imo.

Comment: Accept this answer 'if it helped', and post another question for next issue.